# Relationship between different$L^p (\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mu)$ spaces with $\Omega$ uncountable and $\mu$ being a Radon measure

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, measure-theory, banach-spaces

I earlier asked this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/216155/44557) but I have not had a general classification in the posted answers there. So here is a new question.

I am looking now for some special cases as suggested in one of the comments. Consider the space $L^p (\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mu)$
where $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mu)$ is some measure space satisfying $\Omega$
being uncountable, $\mu$ being a Radon measure and $p \in [1, \infty]$. Is it
true that $L^p \subseteq L^q$ for $q \leqslant p$ and if not, what are some
known counter-examples?

I would be quite satisfied with just references to articles or sections in books!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $\Omega = \mathbb{N}$ with $\mu$ counting measure.  Consider $f(n) = n^\alpha$.  Exercise: For which $p$ (in terms of $\alpha$) is $f \in L^p$?

This holds if $\mu$ is a *finite* measure, and otherwise it usually does not.