# Under what condition two Lp spaces contain the same functions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When $L_p = L_q$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9692/when-l-p-l-q)

Can anyone tell me under what condition these  two spaces $L^p(\mu)$ and $L^s(\mu)$ contain the same functions?

Comment: My bet (assuming $p\ne s$): Only when these spaces are finite dimensional, i.e., when the total space is the finite union of atoms.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen: It seems that Nate's answer in [When $L_p=L_q$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/9692) confirms your bet.

Comment: @lp-man: Indeed it does. No surprise there.